# Vulkan and older APIs memory usage

Tags: vulkan

I'm new to vulkan. The problem is with transforming objects. When using DX11 and OpenGL I used to update the uniform buffer and then send the draw command to the gpu but in vulkan all commands are pre-recorded. So i don't see any way I can do this. I read online that to transform each object I can use an array of uniform buffers and index from it when drawing. Is this the only way to transform each object in vulkan?

If it is then isn't vulkan using more memory than older APIs? Older APIs can have a single uniform buffer and update it before a draw call but in vulkan we have use a buffer for every object. Vulkan is popular as a high performance API but older APIs are using less memory.

If it isn't how can I do this more efficiently?
Thanks.

Comment: Updating the uniform buffer is a command as well, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah but we can use a separate command buffer for that.

Comment: How large exactly are your uniforms that you are even worried about memory?? Few kB won't save you, when you then start uploading your 4k textures or something.

Comment: We can use separate command buffers for drawing objects too but it will cost more memory for command buffers

Comment: Just transformation matrices for now :D

Comment: CPU\GPU time vs memory tradeofs aside; how do you know Vulkan is using (significantly) more memory than let's say OGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is perfectly valid to pretend Vulkan is OpenGL\immediate API:

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ){
    cmdbuff.begin(); cmdUpdateUniform(u[i]); cmdbuff.end();
    vkQueueSubmit( q, cmdbuff ); // lookitme ama glUniform*()
    // some sychronization omitted 

    cmdbuff.begin(); vkCmdDraw(obj[i]); cmdbuff.end();
    vkQueueSubmit( q, cmdbuff ); // lookitme ama glDraw*()
    vkQueueWaitIdle( q ); // lookitme ama glFinish()
}
```

There's a problem with this though. OpenGL driver would try to optimize this using latency vs throughput tradeof. But in Vulkan we like to have some amount of control over latency, so Vulkan driver won't (shouldn't) optimize it that way.

So we can try to guess what the OpenGL driver would do:

```
cmdbuff.begin();
for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ){
    cmdUpdateUniform(u[i]);  // probably vkCmdUpdateBuffer     
    // some sychronization omitted   
    vkCmdDraw(obj[i]);
}
cmdbuff.end();

vkQueueSubmit( q, cmdbuff );
```

As you can see the memory use is back (`vkCmdUpdateBuffer` stores all the uniforms in the command buffer), and OpenGL driver probably has to do the same if it hopes to be performant (in attempt to aggregate all draws to one GPU submit).

There is a small problem with this approach too. All the `vkCmdDraw` uses the same uniform\buffer memory, so previous `vkCmdDraw` needs to finish using that uniform before it is updated. There is potential benefit in allowing the driver to proceed, and in not having to synchronize the `vkCmdDraw` and the subsequent uniform update.

There comes in the info you read online. One way would be to have an array of uniforms and access the appropriate one using index.
Another would be to bind different descriptors or `pDynamicOffsets` via `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets`.

---

Note on memory use:

4x4 sp matrix is 64 B. Assuming you have let's say 1024 3D objects that is 64 kB. In this day and age that is insignificant as main\GP GPU memory is concerned and will be dwarfed by even a single texture or other resources you will need.

If you experience significantly higher memory use, the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Excellent answer sir. I just have one question though. You said "OpenGL driver probably has to do the same if it hopes to be performant (in attempt to aggregate all draws to one GPU submit)." but does OGL driver send all draw commands in a single submit? Doesn't it submit whenever we call glDrawArrays?

Comment: @IAS0601 I must admit I somehow suck at OGL, but I would assume it does not. It is up to the driver to decide. Otherwise `glFlush` command would not exist. I really should not call OpenGL "immediate". It is something in between. For purposes of other commands it pretends to be immediate, but there is no guarantee a side effect of a command finishes before it returns (it may finish during next command call if needed by that call, or at the latest when subsequent `glFlush` command returns.)

Comment: s/`glFlush`/`glFinish`

Comment: @IAS0601 From what I know, OpenGL driver builds command buffers similar to Vulkan's command buffers, because it is much better to send commands in bulks than individually. But the size of these command buffers is unknow and depends on the implementation. We also don't know when they are "created" and "destroy". That's why glFlush() and glFinish() commands exist.

Comment: @Ekzuzy thanks. I think I have use a uniform buffer for every object then?

Comment: Isn't the size of push constants enough? If not, then You have to use uniform buffers. But You need to test which approach is better both for You and for performance. It can be one uniform buffer per object (but I'm not sure if the is no limit to the total number of uniform buffers) or it can be a single uniform buffer with an array of matrices. But there is still limit of the total size of uniform buffer. If You hit it, maybe texel buffers will be good. With that You can have thousands or even millions of objects with corresponding values stored in texel buffers. But this is up to You.

Answer (score 3):

In high-level graphics APIs like OpenGL, uniform variables were also located in a global/general uniform buffer. For convenience, it was just not exposed to developers. But uniform variables updates were performed in a similar way as in Vulkan - it was a normal data transfer to a uniform buffer.

Now if You want to update a uniform variable just before drawing an object, You can do exactly the same in Vulkan. There are methods like vkCmdUpdateBuffer() or vkCmdCopyBuffer() which does exactly that. But why developers are not using such approach? Due to synchronization and impact on performance. In OpenGL this was done automatically by the driver, but it had the same impact as in Vulkan. It just wasn't exposed to developers. Vulkan shows that this isn't the best approach if You are thinking about performance. Keeping an array of uniform buffers (one per object) or a single uniform buffer with an array of uniform variables is better. You can also use push constants for this purpose. Using them is similar to the old, OpenGL-like updating uniform variables stored in a global namespace, but the amount of data is limited (128 bytes guaranteed by the spec).